# How can I put an if statement inside of a createCriteria in grails?

Tags: grails, criteria, hibernate-criteria

I'm new in grails and I have a problem. I have a method that receive some data and match the data with a createCriteria and return the data. It's working fine, but that I want to do now if match with the five params that I have in the method and if match return the data, if not match with the five params, try if match with four params and return the data, if not match with the four params, try if match with three and return the data....

But not really sure how can I put all this in a if statement and return my result.dataPerson or maybe I have to find another way to do it.

My method:

```
def getPersonData(String name, String surname, String address, String phone){


    def searchdataPerson = ClientConfig.createCriteria()
    def result = searchdataPerson.get{
        and{
            or{
                eq('surname', surname)
                isNull('surname')
            }
            or{
                eq('address', address)
                isNull('address')
            }
            or{
                eq('phone', phone)
                isNull('phone')
            }
            or{
                eq('name', name)
                isNull('name')
            }
        }
        maxResults(1)
    }

    return result.dataPerson
}
```

I'm trying to do something like this but it doesn't work

```
def searchdataPerson = ClientConfig.createCriteria()
        def result = searchdataPerson .get{
            if(eq('name', name) && eq('surname', surname) && eq('address', address) && eq('phone', phone)){
            }else if(eq('name', name) && eq('surname', surname) && eq('address', address)){
            }       
            maxResults(1)
        }
return result.dataPerson
```

I get this error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot get property 'dataPerson' on null object
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Jeff has pointed out above you should really refer to result and you are getting the error because you are getting a result but then trying to return an entity or maybe event object hanging off the result.

What is dataPerson ? is it a relationship hanging off of ClientConfig  i.e belongsTo or hasMany declaration in ClientConfig ?

From all of above it isn't exactly clear but to try and explain it another way, you could use HQL:

```
String  query="""
select new map(c.name as name,c.surname as surname, d as dataPerson)
 from ClientConfig c 


left join c.dataPerson d where 

(c.surname != 'GooglyMoogly' or c.surame is null or c.surname=:surname) and

(c.address != 'Caddyshack' or c.address is null or c.address=:address) and

(c.phone is null or c.phone=:phone) and
(c.name is null or c.name=:name) and

"""
def inputParams=[surname:surname,address:address,phone:phone,name:name]

       def result =  ClientConfig.executeQuery(query,inputParams,[readOnly:true,timeout:15,max:1])

    result?.each { output ->

  println "--- ${output?.name} ???? ${output.surname} ???? "

   output?.dataPerson.each { dp ->
      println "--- ${dp.name} ???? "
   }
}
```

Some of above may not be correct but may help you decipher what it is you are trying to achieve.

In the above HQL statement I have done a left join between clientConfig and dataPerson. This is assuming

```
class ClientConfig {

   static hasMany= [dataPerson:DataPerson]
}
```

The left join will mean even when dataPerson does not exist it will attempt to join the (null object)

When iterating if all I wanted was the aspects hanging off of dataPerson then

```
 result?.each { output ->
   // if hasMany
     println "${output.dataPerson[0].name}"
   // if a belongsTo or a direct relation:
     println "${output.dataPerson.name}"
}
```

And to save on doing any of this if you define the actual elements you wish to collect in your HQL then your final iteration will only consist of what it is you asked for exactly and then there is no need to forward walk through the class.

```
String  query="""
    select new map(d.name as name,d.surname as surname, d.address as address)
     from ClientConfig c 
...
```

You now have objects here no need to expand from result to result.dataSet ....:

```
 result?.each { output ->
   println " $output.name $output.surname $output.address "
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I can't tell from your example what you are really trying to do but you can put if statements in side the closure anywhere normal Groovy language rules would allow:

```
def getPersonData(String name, String surname, String address, String phone){


def searchdataPerson = ClientConfig.createCriteria()
def result = searchdataPerson.get{
    and{
        if(surname != 'GooglyMoogly') {
            or{
                eq('surname', surname)
                isNull('surname')
            }
        }
        if(address != 'Caddyshack') {
            or{
                eq('address', address)
                isNull('address')
            }
        }
        // ...
    }
    maxResults(1)
}

return result.dataPerson
}
```

Comment: Hi Jeff. Take a look to my question. I just edit it that I'm doing. Yes, the problem is that I have to match the four params in the same if statement, and I can't hardcode the code, because I don't now what data can match whit surname surname != 'GooglyMoogly'

Comment: The code does not make sense to me.  You are doing something like `def result = searchdataPerson.get { ... }` and inside of that closure you are referring to `result.configJson`.  That is non-sensical.

Comment: You are trying to refer to `result` in the block that is initializing `result`.

Comment: Yes, sorry. ok, I put it out of the method and I get that is null

Comment: Moving it outside of the method isn't the solution.  It is difficult to tell for sure but it looks like you are trying to reference the result of the query in the query criteria, which doesn't make sense.

Comment: The code sample has changed enough that my previous comments won't make sense to anyone trying to follow this later.  I am sorry that I can't help.  Best of luck!